# Finding birth/baptism record (ca 1812) for Charles H. Cox born in North Carolina?

Tags: 19th-century, north-carolina, 1810s

I would like to find a birth or baptism record for my 2nd great grandfather Charles H. Cox, in order to identify his father.  His father I'm told was from the United Kingdom.

The timeline I have for Charles H. Cox is:

- born about 1812 in North Carolina (county unknown)

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user e sure to take the [Tour] to learn how the site works.  I hope you do not mind that I have taken the liberty of editing your question (there is an **edit** button beneath it that you can use to do the same) to focus on the particular question that you are asking.  I suspect that you will be able to progress your search for Charles' father quickest by including more details about Charles like his wife's name, data of birth, where born and where and when they married, and their children's names, dates and locations of birth.

Comment: It would help if you could include a brief list of what sources of information you have so far for him.

Comment: Is this the Charles H Cox to whom you are referring? "United States Census, 1860," database, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M6GN-CRF : accessed 30 July 2015), Charles H Cox, , Rankin, Mississippi, United States; from "1860 U.S. Federal Census - Population," database, Fold3.com (http://www.fold3.com : n.d.); citing p. 68, household ID 460, NARA microfilm publication M653 (Washington, D.C.: National Archives and Records Administration, n.d.); FHL microfilm 803,590.  If so then the **edit** button can be used to copy this into your question.